# Acessing $eip via gdb fails in real mode

Tags: x86, gdb, nasm, ld, real-mode

I'm trying to debug an x86 bootloader I am writing using gdb. Since gdb doesn't seem to handle 16-bit real mode very well I am using a [gdb script](https://github.com/mhugo/gdb_init_real_mode/blob/master/gdbinit_real_mode.txt) someone else wrote for this purpose.

A minimal example of the code I'm trying to debug looks like this (file `asm/boot.asm`):

```
bits 16

global _start

_start:
  ; zero DS
  xor ax, ax
  mov ds, ax

  ; TODO

sleep:
  jmp sleep

  times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; zero out rest of section
  dw 0xAA55             ; add boot signature (needed by qemu)
```

I execute the following commands to create a debuggable elf file from this as well as a flat binary that I copy to the beginning of a dummy floppy disk image:

```
nasm -i asm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf asm/boot.asm -o out/boot.o
ld -Ttext=0x7c00 -melf_x86_64 out/boot.o -o out/boot.elf
objcopy -O binary out/boot.elf out/boot.img
dd if=/dev/zero of=imgs/os.flp bs=512 count=1000
dd if=out/boot.img of=imgs/os.flp bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

I run this image under `qemu` with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -drive format=raw,file=imgs/os.flp,index=0,if=floppy -S -s &
```

And attach gdb with:

```
gdb out/boot.elf \
    -ex "target remote localhost:1234" \
    -x gdbinit_real_mode.txt \
    -ex "break _start" \
    -ex "continue"
```

where `gdbinit_real_mode.txt` is the linked script.

This doesn't really work, because the script contains a function `compute_regs` that set (among others) `$rip` to `$cs * 16 + $eip`. I understand that this is done because in real mode memory is addressed using segment + offset registers but gdb is not aware of this by itself. However, the following gdb command inside `compute_regs` fails with "Invalid cast" (and it seems that actually any access to `$eip` fails in this manner):

```
set $rip = ((((unsigned long)$cs & 0xFFFF) << 4) + ((unsigned long)$eip & 0xFFFF)) & $ADDRESS_MASK
```

Why is that and how can I fix it? I'm using `nasm 2.15.05`, `qemu 5.1.0` and `gdb 9.2` on a 64 bit Linux host.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That was indeed the issue, building for i386 works and I will try adapting the script for x86_64 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script was designed to be used while GDB is running in 32-bit mode. GDB is assuming 64-bit code because you are using a 64-bit ELF file to debug from. Since this isn't 64-bit code you could change NASM's command line to use `-f elf32` instead of `-f elf64` and then use the LD option `-melf_i386` instead of `-melf_x86_64`. Doing this should generate a 32-bit ELF executable and the script should work.

Alternatively if you want to use that script with a 64-bit ELF you will probably have to changed `$eip` to `$rip`.

I would also recommend then using `qemu-system-i386` when debugging 32-bit code via GDB. You may run into more issues if you use `qemu-system-x86_64` when trying to debug 32-bit ELF executables running in 16-bit mode.